# Excel VBA copy works on my computer but not my friend's

Tags: excel, vba

StackOverflow and VBA newbie here making post #1. I can't find another post about this (but search boxes and I don't get along well)

I wrote a macro in Excel that must

1. go to another open workbook (HO_File),
2. copy a range of cells from one sheet and
3. paste-values back in this workbook (Local_File).
4. It will do this several times, copying from different sheets (Bands 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5) of the other workbook.

The problem is it works fine on my computer but crashes on the very first copy command on my friend's computer.

Here is my code up to the With/EndWith where it crashes. (It crashes on the With line that asks it to copy, before it even gets to my unhide commands.)

Questions:

1. Why does it work on my computer but not my friend's? (especially since we're both in Excel 2013) I think the error message I got was "out of range"? but I can't remember for sure. (Yes, I know, I should have written it down)
2. Did I dimension incorrectly?
3. Should I move the unhide commands before the With/EndWith?
4. Other?

   ```
   ' Dimensioning for variables
   Dim HO_File As String
   Dim Local_File As String
   Dim Band_1 As String
   Dim Band_2 As String
   Dim Band_3 As String
   Dim Band_4 As String
   Dim Band_5 As String
   Dim i1 As Long


   ' Set the values of all my variables
       HO_File = [HO_Wkbk_Name] ' This is the name of the head office workbook
       Local_File = [This_Wkbk_Name]
       Band_1 = [Band_1_Sheet]
       Band_2 = [Band_2_Sheet]
       Band_3 = [Band_3_Sheet]
       Band_4 = [Band_4_Sheet]
       Band_5 = [Band_5_Sheet]

   ' Unhide all relevant worksheets in this workbook
   ' Copy the headers from the Band_1 sheet from the HO file
   ' to the orange section of the "Copy" sheet of the local workbook

   With Workbooks(HO_File).Sheets(Band_1).Range("C19:W22").Copy 'This is the line that crashes
       Workbooks(Local_File).Sheets("Copy").Visible = True
       Workbooks(Local_File).Sheets("MacroCalcs").Visible = True
       Workbooks(Local_File).Sheets("Calculations").Visible = True
       Workbooks(Local_File).Sheets("Pivot Data").Visible = True

       Workbooks(Local_File).Sheets("Copy").Select
       Sheets("Copy").Range("A15").Select
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
   End With
   ```

Apologies if I made a mistake in posting. It's late and the brain's fried. Just let me know.

Thank you, in advance.

Esther.

Comment: Are they using the same workbook, or have they copied your macro to their workbook?  (My first guess is that the range names are not defined in the workbook that it is being run in.)

Comment: What is the error message that it throws? In what way does it crash? `Band_1 = [Band_1_Sheet]` looks like incorrect code. String literals need quotes around them, i.e. `Band_1 = "Band_1_Sheet"`, then also make certain a sheet with that name exists

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - `[x]` is equivalent to `ActiveSheet.Range("x")`, so `[Band_1_Sheet]` is accessing the range which has a range name of "Band_1_Sheet" and therefore `Band_1 = [Band_1_Sheet]` (equivalent to `Band_1 = ActiveSheet.Range("Band_1_Sheet").Value`) is assigning the value of that named range to the variable `Band_1`.

Comment: Cool I learnt something new today :)

Comment: Is the `With...End With` needed?  I can't see it being used within the block so could you use just `Workbooks(HO_File).Sheets(Band_1).Range("C19:W22").Copy`  Cuts out one possibility on the error.

Comment: @YowE3K They are using MY workbook. (Actually, I'm sprucing up THEIR workbook) and to make this macro flexible, I've given them a spot on the first page to update the names of the Head Office workbook and the five sheets that have data to be copied. (which I think is what you said to Nick)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I'm not sure if With...End With is needed. I'll try doing without it. So strange though that it worked on my computer and not his!

Comment: What are the values of your `HO_File` and `Band_1` variables when it crashes? (Does your colleague use a different path to the workbook than you do, and you haven't changed the cell in the workbook that says where the file is?)

Comment: @YowE3K My HO_File is the workbook name minus the file extension. My Band_1 variable is the name of the sheet we have to copy the data from. Both the workbook with my macro and the Head Office workbook with the data are in the same folder and both are always open before I run the macro. I removed the "With...EndWith" and moved my unhiding commands to the start and it's crashing on the unhide:
        Workbooks(Local_File).Sheets("Copy").Visible = True
Where Local_File is the name of the active workbook. Am I calling my workbooks incorrectly?

Comment: Check that the workbooks are open in the same **instance** of Excel.  One instance of Excel can't see what is open in another instance of Excel.  If you aren't sure whether they are in the same instance, use `View / Switch Windows` from the menu - if they are in the same instance you will see both workbooks listed - if they are in different instances you will only see one of the workbooks.

Comment: Oh! I never thought of that! Thanks, @YowE3K. But why is my unhide worksheet command is crashing? I'm unhiding a worksheet in the active workbook, not the Head Office workbook.

Comment: Without seeing the exact values of your variables, it's very hard to guess.  By "active workbook", do you mean the one the macros are in?  If so, change `Workbooks(Local_File).` to `ThisWorkbook.`, and therefore avoid any naming issues.  If not, are you sure that `Workbooks(Local_File)` is open in the instance of Excel that is running the macros?